# Execute script from rc.local as user instead of root

Tags: ubuntu, startup-scripts, rc.local

I want to execute a script every time my server start up. The problem is that I need to be a certain user to execute the script, if I try to do it as root it cant find certain packages (such as ruby).

I try to change to xxx user01.

```
sudo su user01
/etc/init.d/script start
```

This doesn't work however.

Comment: Post your init script?

Comment: Do you have some logs ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `su` in the rc script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940771/switch-user-in-a-init-script.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Running `sudo su user01` in a script does not mean the following commands are sent to the resultant shell.  In fact, it likely means a new shell is spawned as user01, which never exits!

Two things:

- You can execute a command as another user either by passing the `-c 'command...'` argument to su, like `su user01 -c '/etc/init.d/script start'`.
- Starting a service that uses /etc/init.d from rc.local isn't the correct thing to do.  You want to use enable the service at startup using your distribution tools, like `chkconfig` or `update-rc.d`.  You also don't want jobs in /etc/init.d that shouldn't be started as `root`.  The jobs themselves can feel free to fork to another user account, but should be invoked by root.

Answer (score 10):

You can just run the command through sudo like this:

```
sudo -H -u user01 /etc/init.d/script start
```

-H sets the HOME environment variable to that of the user

-u specifies the username to run as

Answer (score 9):

You could put something in `/etc/crontab` and run it `@reboot`

```
@reboot username /etc/init.d/script start
```

Comment: or in the user's own crontab file.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can't run that script with sudo because of requiretty ( enforces that users must be logged) in sudoers. You may want disable, which is somewhat risky

Also there is a somewhat old tool called runsuid: http://freecode.com/projects/runsuid

HTH